# id of xpath is getting changed every time in selenium python 2.7 chrome

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

one more problem i hv,i asked similar question earlier and i tried that method but not able use that methon in this problem so pls help me. it's element
html code is - Filters

So basically, question is that there is one button its kind of toggle button and i want click on that button to select device like Desktop, Tablet & Mobile all check boxes are already (default) selected now i have to uncheck or deselect device, to do this, first i have to click on that toggle button , when i click on toggle button its id (gwt-uid-598) **598** is getting changed every time or every refresh. Can you pls help me, what should or which method should i follow in this case.

i am using below python code.

## Click on device Filters

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gwt-uid-598"]/div/div/span')
elem.click()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

Try to use another selector, for example: css class or use xpath method `contains()`.

Example: `//div[contains(text(), "checkbox")]`

I can help you if you can provide source code of the page or needed element.

Comment: hi Patti here is element code <button class="N1LCMI-r-a N1LCMI-lg-a N1LCMI-r-j N1LCMI-r-m" id="gwt-uid-3264" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-3264" role="button" type="button" aria-pressed="true"><div class="N1LCMI-r-h"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="gwt-InlineLabel">Filters&nbsp;</span><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAECAYAAABCxiV9AAAAG0lEQVR42mOIjIz8jwszgABOCRjAKYGsAJkPAKT/IKHcRfUJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="7" height="4" class="gwt-Image"></div></div></button>